# What is the syntax to get the "CurlyPhi" symbol?

Tags: symbols

What is the syntax to get the "CurlyPhi" symbol in TeX/LaTeX?

To get phi we use, `$\Phi$`.

Comment: Are you looking for `\varphi`?  See also [how to look up a symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

Comment: As @ScottH. suggests, `\varphi` might be the symbol you want. If not, please edit your question and add a picture of the symbol you want to typeset.

Answer (score 46):

to get curly phi, use the following:

> $\varphi$